# Add SubLayer to CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` with an path set to `shapeLayer.path`
I want to add a subLayer on top of the path.
However by adding the sublayer using `[shapeLayer addSublayer:layer]` the path is drawn above the sublayer.
Is there a way to get the sublayer on top of the path?

Comment: `CGMutablePathRef shapeLayerPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(myShapeLayer.path);CGPathAddPath(shapeLayerPath, nil, myLayerOverShapeLayer.path);myShapeLayer.path = shapeLayerPath;`

Answer (score 3):

You could have one `CALayer` and add the `CAShapeLayer` and the other layer you want on top to it:

```
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:parentLayer];

[parentLayer addSublayer: myShapeLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer: myLayerOverShapeLayer];
```

Comment: @pre do you mind accepting my answer if it was the one you were looking for?

Comment: Your proposal needs an additional layer. Of course that works, but I would love to get it work without the additional layer.

Answer (score -1):

You could just do this:

```
[shapeLayer.superlayer insertSublayer:subLayer above:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: In my problem the layer will be moved and animated, when using your proposal, I would have to move/animate two layers, so it is not really a solution to the problem I had.

Comment: he requested something else